# what happend when I close the buffer of stdin and ungetc to stdin?

Tags: c++, linux, io, buffer

It came into my mind when I was reading a book about programming on linux, I tried it on my computer and the code worked fine, but I just could not understand how it worked like that, hope someone could help me explain it, thanks in advance!
my code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    unsigned char ch = 'a';
    unsigned char pch = ungetc(ch, stdin);
    char c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is c++ why don't you use `ifstream` and the `cin` operator?

Comment: yes, it is c++ style which is what I am familiar with, and I just want to verify the `ungetc` functionality and buffer of input stream.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of buffer setting, `ungetc` must always be able to push one character back into the input stream. If you attempt to push more than one character, `ungetc` may fail. (You should check the return value for failure.)

> One character of pushback is guaranteed. If the ungetc function is called too many times on the same stream without an intervening read or file positioning operation on that stream, the operation may fail. (§7.21.7.10/para. 3)

So a single `ungetc` is valid, even if there is no input buffer.

Comment: From what you have stated and as my humble opinion, `ungetc` may put the character input a special buffer, and every time standard input stream wants to get a character, it first tries reading from the speicial buffer, and then from the normal buffer which I have set to NULL, am I right?

Comment: @kuixiong: if you consider a single `char` to be a buffer, that is precisely correct.